# I have to index around 4000 files in lucene .it always gives me a heap space exception with eclipse.

Tags: java, lucene

I have to index around 4000 files in lucene .it always gives me a heap space exception with eclipse.
The total files size is 5.9 Gb.
Is 6 GH i5 processor
Is there any
 Other way to do it.
Please help guys.

Comment: @ZoveGames, That's a proper answer rather than a comment.

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362460/why-does-lucene-cause-oom-when-indexing-large-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse you can open the run configuration dialog in the context menu next to the run button. 
Add `-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M` under VM arguments, which will set the heap space to be 1024 MB or 1 GB. If it still throws OutOfMemoryError then try 2048 instead of 1024,or any power of two. Make sure your computer has that much MB RAM though. If that still doesn't work I don't know what will apart from writing your program in a C language... Hope this helps...