# Out of memory while indexing with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.9.0 to index 23k files, but now I'm receiving `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` message .
I don't want to increase "heap size" because the number of files tends to increase everyday.
How can I index all files without the OOM problem and increase "heap space"?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague and makes little sense.

First of all, 23K files can be 1 byte/each or 1G/each. How are we supposed to know what's inside and how heavyweight they are?

Secondly, you say

> I don't want to increase "heap size" because <...>

and straight after you say

> How can I index all files without the OOM problem and increase "heap space"

Can you make up your mind on whether you can increase heap space or not?

There's a certain amount of memory required to index the data, and there's nothing much you can do about it. That said, the most memory required is during merging process and you can [play with the merge factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362460/why-does-lucene-cause-oom-when-indexing-large-files) to see if this helps you.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistency, I don't want to increase the heap size. I have about 13G of files with variable sizes. Thanks !

Comment: You can take your numbers and run them through [memory and storage estimator](http://searchhub.org/2011/09/14/estimating-memory-and-storage-for-lucenesolr/) too see (roughly) where you stand. But that fact is that you can't buy a new Ferrari for $100, no matter what your wishes are.